# Why is the Russian word Лошадь (horse) so similar to the word площадь (square)?

Tags: этимология

I am just starting to learn Russian and I noticed that these 2 words are very similar.  Are they actually related?  Is a square a place to keep your horse?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems unlikely that they are related. Various online sources (wiktionary.org, lexicography.online) say that лошадь derives etymologically from Turkic languages, while площадь is either from Proto-Slavic or from Greek. Perhaps someone can cite an authoritative source.

Comment: the etymology of both words is easily googleable. for instance, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C

Comment: They are not related any more than English "place" and "lace" are.

Comment: Not a similar. No, the "лошадь" and "площадь" have not any connections.

Comment: But if you call as "similar" - exactly the suffix of words, ha ha... :) "-адь" in this case...  Then welcome in the Inflectional-Synthethic languages. :))) 
There are a tons these.. "similarities"... :) in this. This is the system of the word's constructing..
In this case this suffix show that words are the feminne gender.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are not related any more than English "mare" and "square" are.

*Лошадь* is believed to originate from Turkic languages.

*Площадь* is a native Russian word, ultimately from a Proto-Indo-European etymon, which is also a distant ancestor of the English word "flake".

There are lots words in Russian. For purely statistical reasons, coincidences like this are dime a dozen.